# IdentityServer AccessToken one server to another server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have on web API and IdentityServer4  app running on windows server "Server 1" and we are using "access_token " to authorize API call.
Now client want to deploy the IdentityServer4 app in one more another windows server "Server 2". I followed the following steps to do this.

1.Created the certificate using openssll.

2.Converted the certificate to .pfx with password.

3.Added below code to Load the certificate from windows store

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
            using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                    // for dev only
                    "57041fcc9086da18419999fbb9276bd59bd8d14a",false);

                    cert = certCollection[0];
            }          
            return cert;
```

4. Copied the .pfx file in to both server 1 and 2 and installed the same.

5.Now I generate the access_token from Server 2 and passing this token to web API(running on Server 1) and "Authority" pointing to IdentityServer running on Server 1.

But this is not working and i'm getting "Unauthorized" error.

Its clearly shows that something im doing wrong here.

Please guide me , Thanks in Advance

Access Token Request:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVg7V.png)

Token Response: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OetEw.png)

Token compare from 2 server :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23hfW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple identity servers, then they must share the same signing key.

See is [page](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html?highlight=key%20material#key-material) about key material.

If you use AddDeveloperSigningCredential, then each machine will have a different set of private/public keys.

The HTTPS certificate is not the same as the token signing certificate. If this is not the problem, it might be that the audience does not match the expected audience when the client receives the token. Do check out the [ValidateAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validateaudience?view=azure-dotnet) parameter. For simplicity, the audience (aud claim) in the token should be the same from both IdentityServers.

If the from the authentication classes does not help you, then you can always I disable all the token validation features in this [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet) and then enable them one by one to figure what is causing you problems.

If could also be the issuer issue, as the two tokens have different issues, perhaps the clients expects a specific issuer in the tokens. Perhaps you should put a load-balancer in front of the two IdentityServers so that they will have the same issuer?

Comment: Thanks but Im not using DeveloperSigningCreditential. I created the certificate and installed the same in both servers

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: I verified the token generated from server 1 and server 2  And Aud,Scope,Client_id  are same in both token. I added the screenshot for reference . Can you please guide what could be the issue here.

Comment: I would look at the log in your clients to see why it fails.. You can also play with the tokenvalidation parameters.

Comment: I clarified my anwser, does that help?

Comment: Great and Thanks .Im following your suggestion to catch the issue. will update more.

Comment: Feel free to approve my answer if you like it.